# Using Lambda inside VPC with SNS+RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns, amazon-vpc

I'd like to have a lambda expression that every hour makes a query on RDS database, pull some ARN (device tokens) and then sends these devices a notification via SNS. My desire is to remain inside the VPC and I'd like to avoid using NAT due to its cost. Should i create a VPC endpoint (is this called AWS PrivateLink?) that can reach out SNS+RDS? Is NAT and Endpoint similar in billing? Globally is this the right way to achieve a "cron sending notifications" on AWS?

RDS is reachable inside the VPC without the endpoint isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possibly

Your lambda can run in a private subnet in the VPC that communicates with your RDS database over the network on port 3306. Make sure your security group and NACL rules allow this.

You then need to create a VPC endpoint to your SNS service. Be sure your route table includes this route.

The main difference between VPC endpoints and AWS Privatelink is the following:

A VPC endpoint enables you to privately connect your VPC to supported AWS services. SNS, Kinesis, SQS, S3,....

While AWS Privatelink is more about creating your own application in your VPC and configuring it as an AWS PrivateLink-powered service (referred to as an endpoint service). Other AWS principals can create a connection from their VPC to your endpoint service using an interface VPC endpoint.

VPC endpoints are free. Nat Gateways cost per hour per GB.

Comment: I've managed to use SNS from Lambda adding inbound rule for all traffic coming from the same security group Lambda belong to. Now the RDS is not working...I can't reach it from Lambda, maybe the problem is that my db instance is public? Any solution to that?

Comment: Have you checked your security group or NACL settings? Public subnet should not effect it.

Comment: Lambda and RDS should have different security groups? Or I can reuse the same setting inbound 3306 for the same SG? Should i use NACL? Or I can leave them default? Thanks.

Comment: Networking can be tricky you should move your db into a private subnet. You need to allow 3306 and ephemeral port range 1024-65535 in all the security groups and NACLs

Comment: I need to keep RDS publicy available, is this not compatible with accessing It from Lambda in VPC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203149/discussion-between-jumpa-and-david-webster).